# Physics formula implementation issues

Tags: javascript, math, physics

I'm trying to implement the formulas necessary to calculate the global radiation incident on an inclined solar panel.

The formulas I use were found in the following research paper :

--> ipac.kacst.edu.sa/eDoc/2010/191048_1.pdf

Here is the commented JavaScript code :

```
var config = require('./configuration.json'),
    pi = Math.PI;

function solar_efficiency(angle, day) {
    var R_mD,  // average sun-earth distance (m)
        a,     // semi-major axis (km)
        e,     // oval orbit eccentricity (km)
        theta, // angle with the perihelion
        n,     // current nth day of the year (int)
        R_D,   // actual sun-earth distance (m)
        I_o;   // extraterrestrial radiation (indice)

    R_mD = config.avg_sun_earth_dist;
    a = config.semi_major_axis;
    e = config.eccentricity;
    n = day;
    theta = n * 365.25 / 360;
    R_D = a * (1 - e * e) / (1 + e * Math.cos(theta));
    I_o = 1367 * Math.pow(R_mD / R_D, 2);

    var axis,  // angle of the earth's axis
        D;     // sun declination (radian)

    axis = config.earth_axis;
    D = ((axis * pi) / 180) * Math.sin(((2 * pi) * (284 + n)) / 365);

    var Eq_t;  // solar time correction (float)

    if((1 <= n) && (n <= 106)) {
        Eq_t = -14.2 * Math.sin((pi * (n + 7)) / 111);
    }
    else if((107 <= n) && (n <= 166)) {
        Eq_t = 4.0 * Math.sin((pi * (n - 106)) / 59);
    }
    else if((167 <= n) && (n <= 246)) {
        Eq_t = -6.5 * Math.sin((pi * (n - 166)) / 80);
    }
    else if((247 <= n) && (n <= 365)) {
        Eq_t = 16.4 * Math.sin((pi * (n - 247)) / 113);
    }

    var Long_sm,    // longitude of the standard meridian (longitude)
        Long_local, // longitude of the panels (longitude)
        T_local,    // local time (h)
        T_solar;    // solar time (h)

    Long_sm = config.std_meridian_long;
    Long_local = config.current_longitutde;
    T_local = config.local_time;
    T_solar = T_local + (Eq_t / 60) + ((Long_sm - Long_local) / 15);

    var W; // hour angle (radian)

    W = pi * ((12 - T_solar) / 12);

    var Lat_local,  // latitude of the panels (latitude)
        W_sr,       // sunrise hour angle (°)
        W_ss;       // sunset hour angle (°)

    Lat_local = config.current_latitude;
    W_sr = W_ss = Math.acos(-1 * Math.tan(Lat_local) * Math.tan(D));

    var alpha, // angle between solar panel and horizontal (°)        -FIND!!!
        R_b;   // ratio of avg. beam radiation on horiz. / inclined surface

    alpha = angle; // /!\ TESTING ONLY /!\

    var num_1 = Math.cos(Lat_local - alpha) * Math.cos(D) * Math.sin(W_ss);
    var num_2 = W_ss * Math.sin(Lat_local - alpha) * Math.sin(D);
    var det_1 = Math.cos(Lat_local) * Math.cos(D) * Math.sin(W_ss);
    var det_2 = W_ss * Math.sin(Lat_local) * Math.sin(D);

    R_b = (num_1 + num_2) / (det_1 + det_2);  // in the northern hemisphere

    var H_g, // global radiation on horizontal surface (W h/m^2/day)  ---DB!!!
        H_d, // diffuse radiation on horizontal surface (W h/m^2/day) ---DB!!!
        H_B; // beam radiation on inclined surface (W h/m^2/day)

    H_g = 700;
    H_d = 500;
    H_B = (H_g - H_d) / R_b;

    var R_d; // ratio of avg. daily diffuse radiation tilted / horiz. surface

    R_d = (3 + Math.cos(2 * alpha)) / 2; // isotropic Badesco model

    var H_D; // sky-diffuse radiation on inclined surface (W h/m^2/day)

    H_D = R_d * H_d;

    var p,   // albedo std. = 0.2 (soil = 0.17, grass = 0.25, concrete = 0.55)
        H_R; // ground reflected radiation on inclined surface (W h/m^2/day)

    p = config.ground_albedo;
    H_R = H_g * p * ((1 - Math.cos(alpha)) / 2);

    var H_T; // daily global radiation on a tilted surface (W h/m^2/day)

    H_T = H_B + H_D + H_R;
    return H_T;
}

var results = {}, current_day;
for(var i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    current_day = [];
    for(var k = 0; k <= 90; k++) {
        current_day.push([k, solar_efficiency(k, i)]);
    }
    current_day.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });
    current_day.length = 1;
    results[i] = current_day[0];
}

console.log(results);
```

The configurations like latitude and longitude are situated in a JSON file.
Here are the values I'm testing the program with :

```
{
    "avg_sun_earth_dist" : 149597870.7,
    "earth_axis" : 23.45,

    "eccentricity" : 0.0167,
    "semi_major_axis" : 149598261,

    "local_time" : 12,

    "std_meridian_long" : 0,
    "current_longitude" : 2.294351,
    "current_latitude" : 48.858844,

    "ground_albedo" : 0.2
}
```

If you change the latitude a little bit you will see that you either get NaNs or the values stabilize but suddenly for certain values of "i" just skyrocket.

The problem seems to be this line :

```
W_sr = W_ss = Math.acos(-1 * Math.tan(Lat_local) * Math.tan(D));
```

I'm not sure if the input data is wrong and thus crashes the program or if I just implemented the formulas wrong.

Comment: arccos(x) is defined for -1 =< x =< 1

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm not really sure why in this context it goes under / above these values although the formula should be used with this input format.

Comment: `tanx` can go from `-inf` to `+inf` so you definetly get a `NaN` if **-1 * Math.tan(Lat_local) * Math.tan(D)** goes out of `[-1;1]`

Comment: After logging a bit before posting, my conclusion was that the problem is that the result of (-1 * Math.tan(Lat_local) * Math.tan(D)) sometimes inferior to -1 and superior to 1. But like I said before. I don't know where I'm going wrong compared to the research paper.

Comment: It seems that your input data is incorrect.
This isn't a code problem it's a mathematics concept issue.
Ask here http://math.stackexchange.com or http://physics.stackexchange.com but don't scare them with code if you want answers. Ask strictly about the formula and the input data.

Comment: You probably want to convert `Lat_local` to radians. In fact, all of your cos() and tan() and sin() functions should have inputs of radians.

Comment: They might be in radians `"current_longitude" : 2.294351` is a possible value using radians. It might be a bigger misconcept

Comment: I think you are right Phil Bozak, I'm going to test the code with radians. The 2nd page of the research paper indicates degrees, but I guess they just made a mistake.

Comment: @Awake Zoldiek You might have ended up with `floating point` miscalculation. You know that thay are damn inacurate right? I'm pretty sure that this is the problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems

Comment: Ok, so I tested the code with latitude = 0.8527476965182763 and longigtude = 0.040043979146424415 and the program doesn't get NaNs anymore but still peeks at some points. Some times there is a difference of one or two powers of ten.

Comment: That line certainly looks wrong. Perhaps you could indicate where in the paper you got it. More importantly **you should always start small and simple and build up**. Try it without eccentricity, ground albedo or axial tilt; don't go any farther until that works perfectly. If you type in a mass of code like this, implementing math you don't understand, it cannot work.

Comment: Eccentricity and axial tilt are constants that I found on the Internet, so there shouldn't be a real problem here. The ground albedo value was the same as the one of the research paper.

Answer (score 0):

Use that [**library**](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) , `floats` aren't good for such calculations. You'll always end up with errors. In every language for such arithmetics are used `BigDecimal`s